# double buttonpress is needed before php code does what it is supposed to

Tags: php, html

Ok this is the issue, to the left of my website there is a zone where it says on every webpage: **you are logged in as "user"** followed by a logout button.
When someone presses the logout button, the person is logged out.
But **you are logged in as "user"** remains seen, even though the form is submitted and the person is logged out. After pressing logout the second time it removes the message + the button.

this is the code:

```
<?php 


    if ($_SESSION['login']== "OK") { 
    echo "Je bent ingelogd als ".$_SESSION['Gebruiker']."<br/>";
    ?>
    <form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' name='btnLogout' value='Logout'></form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnLogout'])){
        $_SESSION['login']= "";



        }
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check $_POST *before* you output whether the user is logged or not.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['btnLogout']))
    $_SESSION['login']= "";

if ($_SESSION['login']== "OK")
{
    echo "Je bent ingelogd als ".$_SESSION['Gebruiker']."<br/>";
?>
<form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' name='btnLogout' value='Logout'></form>
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow this is really the easy fix that I needed, I get it :D